# Error code 500, I have an error while I am trying to view index.php file

Tags: php

Dear People who will read this

I was programming php by fallowing tutorial with phpacademy Login and Register tutorial before that it was fine and I noticed after I closed terminal it gave me 500 Error code it also says The website encountered an error while retrieving nameofmydomain/lr/index.php.

> localhost is my server name

It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly

Code for the index.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
 <div id="container">
<?php include 'includes/aside.php'; ?>

 <h1>Home</h1>
 <p>Just a template.</p>
  </div>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php';
</body>
</html>
```

All I did is fallowed tutorial in video 3 by including head,header,aside,footer, pretty much I am linking php files to index.php file. I don't know why it gave me error server error code 500. I already cleared cache deleted cookies, after I deleted cookies I restarted my browser and it still gives me an error. Any suggestions, any help, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely
Guy who needs help with his localhost server.

I already read error log  so I'm gonna say on line 13 there  opening and closing script tag.